# D3: Overlay Svg and Canvas: geo Projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg

I am plotting a map of NYC (interactive svg) and need to overlay it with the canvas with thousands of points. Using [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/boeric/aa80b0048b7e39dd71c8fbe958d1b1d4) I was able to achieve almost what I want: there is an overlay and points are visible.

However, despite using the same projection and having canvas within svg and with the same width and height, points are offset from the svg borders by some specific amount:

[image]

This offset remains even through resize, and I can't get where is an error.
Here is the snippet of my code:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .center([-73.98, 40.72])
    .scale(width * 74)
    .translate([(width) / 2, (height) / 2]);
...

var svg = d3.select("#svg-container")
.append("svg")
.attr("class", "map");

// CANVAS PART
var foreignObject = svg.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "overlay");

// add embedded body to foreign object
var foBody = foreignObject.append("xhtml:body")
    .style("margin", "0px")
    .style("padding", "0px")
    .style("background-color", "none")
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px");

// add embedded canvas to embedded body
var canvas = foBody.append("canvas")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

// Points
context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
context.globalAlpha = .8;
userpoints.forEach(function(d, i) {
        var crd = projection([d.lat, d.lon]);
        // console.log(crd, );
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(crd[0], crd[1], 1, 1);
        context.fillStyle=comm_colors[d.Community];
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
```

Here is the corresponding part of the resulting DOM:

```
<svg class="map">
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="1036.962" height="1010" class="overlay" style="visibility: visible;">
        <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 1036.96px; height: 1010px;">
            <canvas x="0" y="0" width="1036.962" height="1010"></canvas>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
    <g id="boros"></g>
    <g id="cts">
        <path> ... 
        </path>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="lzssi" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="3" height="3"><rect width="3" height="3" fill="grey"></rect><path d="M 0,3 l 3,-3 M -0.75,0.75 l 1.5,-1.5
M 2.25,3.75 l 1.5,-1.5" stroke-width="0.5" shape-rendering="auto" stroke="white" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: I guess helpers need more details as wich errors, line... in the code and more details like a debugger can do for you, may be you can solve this demand and upload an simple image with the error getting, can be the good way to beening helped. Regards.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, there is no error, things are working fine from computer's point of view. I'll add the dom details, though